# Get integer numbers from percentages

Tags: php, math

Let's say i have a budget of $40 and i want to spend specific percentages on multiple things.

```
$budget = 40;

$food = 60 // 20%
$gas = 26 // 26%
$movie = 14 // 14%

percent($food, $budget) // $24
percent($gas, $budget) // $10.4
percent($movie, $budget) // $5.6
```

The issue is that i don't want to get decimals like that, i'd like to get integer numbers even if i have to lower some and correct the others.

**The total budget should not be less or more than 40.**

How to do that without ending up with a big ol' code?

Comment: I think round to nearest should do the trick, but I don't have any proof.

Comment: @Dani: If you round, 50% of 11 plus 50% of 11 gives you 12. How about this: If you have n budget items, just round for the first n-1 items, and give the n-th whatever's left.

Comment: @grossvogel: and if its 9.5 + 9.5 + 9.5 + 9.5 + 9.5 + 12.5? it will give you 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10, which is way off the (optimal ?) 10 + 9 + 10 + 9 + 10 + 12.

Comment: @Dani: True, that method would be less than optimal in some cases, and the effect could accumulate to be more and more off with more items to round. But plain old rounding actually violates the stated constraints. I can't think of a simple algorithm to always achieve an optimal answer.

Comment: @grossvogel: The hard part here is to value on how optimal the answer is, after that, the algorithm is very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. I didnt test it.

```
function percentCalc ($percent, $budget) [
   $pecentage * .01 = $decimal;
   $unrounded = $decimal * $budget;
   $final = round($unrounded);

   return $final;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest and fairest way I can think of to do this:

1. Round everything down.
2. Add up the rounded values.
3. Compare with the total budget to see how much you have left.
4. Distribute what you have left to the items that lost the most in the rounding.

As for not ending up with a big ol' code, I'd suggest getting *working* code first, then work on making it more pleasing to the eye. You can even write some tests to make sure you don't break it as you go.